# MongoDB Equivalent of SELECT DISTINCT on Multiple Columns

Tags: pandas, mongodb, aggregate, pymongo

I'm very new to MongoDB. I'm trying to query a collection with documents that follow this structure (There's a lot more fields but only need these two):

```
{game_id: xxxxxxx,
 season: 2020,
 schedule: { 
      game_key:
  }
}
```

I'm trying to grab all of the distinct game_ids and game_keys, basically the equivalent of SELECT DISTINCT game_id, game_key FROM x WHERE season = 2020.

From what I've researched if you're trying to get the distinct based on multiple columns you need to use an aggregate:

```
cursor = collection.aggregate([{ '$group': {'_id': { 'game_id': "$game_id", 'schedule': {"game_key":"$game_key" }}}}])
df = pd.DataFrame(iter(cursor))
print(df.head())
```

However, I'm only going getting an empty DataFrame.

Comment: Maybe have a look at https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/sql-aggregation-comparison/

Comment: Try changing the second field in the _id to reference the nested key instead of nesting it yourself, i.e.: { _id: { "game_id": "$game_id", "game_key": "$schedule.game_key" } }.